# What is the most readily usable form of nutrients/energy source for heterotrophic microorganism in general?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, nutrition

Consider a nutritious mixture containing abundant soluble sugars, soluble lipids and soluble protein etc. Would heterotrophic microbes preferentially use sugars first > lipids > proteins > insoluble polymer such as cellulose (please propose your own order if this is wrong)? If appropriate, you can further differentiate these compounds into e.g. sugars into monosaccharides and oligosaccharides. Is there a general trend or is it highly variable depending on the particular microbe concerned?

Comment: The generalization is not possible. For example, chemolithoautotrophic bacteria do not use organic molecules or polymers as the source of energy and carbon.

Comment: Thx, I edited the question